# AWS Application Load Balancer Web Socket Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket

I have used EB to create an environment with Tomcat 8, Java 8 configured as load balanced, auto scaling.

Deployed a WebSocket server on this.
On the EC2 running instance, my websocket client (tyrus API) is able to communicate over websocket, for example  **ws://ip/chat**

Now I need a TCP connection (count) based auto scaling strategy, for which switched to Application Load Balancer (ALB) with a target group pointing to this EC2 instance.
Stickiness has been enabled and ALB is using HTTP listener on port 80 with listener rule "/chat" pointing to this target group.

All involved SG have All TCP in and out traffic enabled for testing.

Invoking **ws://ELB/chat** results doesnt work resulting in a 404:

*Caused by: org.glassfish.tyrus.core.HandshakeException: Response code was not 101: 404*

Any inputs on how this should be configured.
Final aim is to be able to communicate with WebSocket server over ALB and then auto scale based on TCP "ActiveConnectionCount"